# Wait query finishes till register new data on table

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, insert

I'm migrating information from sql

```
Table1
Table2
Table3
Table4
```

Table1 is independent
Table2 needs Table1 id
Table3 needs Table2 id
Table5 needs Table1 id
and so on...

There are many tables. I'm migrating all information with SQL INSERT queries

```
insert into table1 (data1,data2) values ('val','val')
insert into table2 (data1,data2,id_table1) values ('val','val',
    (select id from table1 order by id desc limit 1)
)
insert into table3 (data1,data2,id_table1) values ('val','val',
    (select id from table2 order by id desc limit 1)
)
insert into table5 (data1,data2,id_table1) values ('val','val',
    (select id from table1 order by id desc limit 1)
)
```

The problem is: if some users would insert data while I'm executing my queries, and my migration logic would fail.

How can I make stop tables1, table2, table3, table4 registering data till my query finishes? maybe is it possible to use transactional tables, such laravel?

Comment: "Table5 needs Table1 id" -- is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, I could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup depends on the fact that `SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` is always going to give you the `id` that you had inserted.  Therefore, in order for your design to work, you need a consistent state/snapshot from which to look at your data.  Postgres' MVCC frameworks helps you with that: wrapping your transaction around a `BEGIN .. COMMIT` block should help you achieve that--you must also first do `set transaction isolation level repeatable read;` before issuing your first `INSERT` query.  This way, other users can still insert, but you will always see the same snapshot.